# Accessing External HDD

Tags: 11.10, external-hdd

So I have 2 external hdd's mounted. When user1 is logged in, access to those external drives are ok.

When I log off user1 and log in as user2, I cant access those external drives. This is kinda related to another question I have. I think its permissions but have tried a few things to no avail.

Suggestions are welcome and appreciated!

Here's the other issue, which seems related.
[related issue here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103721/samba-share-issues)

Comment: Samba is network file sharing, so is unrelated.  What filesystem do you have the external drive formatted with?

Comment: I know samba is network file sharing but I have shares located on the external hdd's that one user can connect while the other cant.

Comment: Both drives are NTFS formatted. Like I said, when logged in as user1, I can connect to the drive but when connected via user2, I cant connect to them. I guess permissions but when I right click to try and modify the permissions, no change takes effect.

Comment: Would it have something to do with one user having the drive mounted? Would this cause the other user to not be able to connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally NTFS is mounted so that the user who did the mounting has access to all files on the volume ( and others do not ).  See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/74851/8500) for details on how to configure it to store persistent permissions so you can grant both users access no matter who mounted it.

Comment: Would a program called PySDM (Standard Device Manager)? I found this and tested on my laptop while at work. I modified a USB flash drive to have access for all users and my permissions are now as root. I'm thinking this might also work, not sure.